# Oxidation of ethanedioic acid with potassium permanganate

Tags: organic-chemistry, organic-oxidation

> What are the products of the reaction of 1,3-butadiene with hot $\ce{KMnO4}$ (excess)?

I know that $\ce{KMnO4}$ will first cleave the double bonds and we should get
$$\ce{CH2=CH-CH=CH2 ->[KMnO4] 2CH2=O + O=CH-CH=O}$$
Now the aldehydes will further oxidise to
$$\ce{H2C=O <<=> H2C(OH)2 ->[KMnO4] O=C=O}$$
$$\ce{O=CH-CH=O ->[KMnO4] HOOC-COOH}$$

I don't understand how and why $\ce{HO2C-CO2H}$ would further oxidise to $2 \ \ce{CO2}$?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/4310/what-is-the-reaction-between-oxalic-acid-and-potassium-permanganate Related

Comment: @Safdar, the link just provides the balanced equation. But the question is why does it react in the first place? Also what is the mechanism?

Comment: So, acc. to book, answer is 2 + 2 = 4 CO2?

Comment: @RahulVerma, yes that is correct. This question is from Solomon's Organic Chemistry 11e, Problem 13.20 (f), (Chapter 13, pg no 619).

Comment: The KMnO4 oxidation of oxalic acid mechanism is highly complex and is under debate.
This was the most recent [paper](http://math.bme.hu/~jtoth/pubtexts/KovacsVizvariRiedelToth.pdf) I could find with possible mechanisms

Comment: @Safdar, is this reaction true for all general dicarboxylic acids with $\ce{KMnO4}$, or only specific to oxalic acid?

Comment: KMnO4 oxidations are complex in general.